# Approximating e - Getting as many precision digits as possible

Tags: c++, series, approximation

I have been trying to approximate e using series representation to get as many precision digits as possible using the code below, but no matter how many terms I compute, the number of precision digits seems to remain the same. ie:

> 2.71828198432922363281250000000000000000000000000000

Is it my approach that's wrong? 
Here is the code:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 #include <math.h>
  4 using namespace std;
  5 
  6 float factorial (float a)
  7 {
  8         if (a > 1)
  9         {
 10                 return (a * factorial (a-1));
 11         } else
 12         {
 13                 return 1;
 14         }
 15 }
 16 
 17 int main()
 18 {
 19         float sum  = 0;
 20         int range=100000;
 21 
 22         for (int i=0; i<=range;i++)
 23         {
 24                 sum += pow(-1,i)/factorial(i);
 25         }
 26         sum = pow(sum,-1);
 27         printf("%4.50f\n", sum);
 28 }
```

Comment: You are limited by the choice of the data type: you get an error in the 8-th digit. Try using `long double` instead of `float` to see if the results get somewhat better.

Comment: google for "What every computer scientist should know about floating point math".  When your terms get small enough, they no longer have any effect on the sum.

Comment: @gspr: Note the last line before the printf.  Of course, `pow()` is a terribly slow way of doing this.

Comment: This an aside: Why are you calculating 1/e in a loop and then taking the reciproce? Why not replace `pow(-1,i)` with `1.0`, and leave out the `pow(sum,-1)`? (But as others have pointed out, this is not the source of your problems).

Comment: Recomputing the factorial each time is insane. You should store a running term and just divide it each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get more exact digits, you should write your on data class which store more digit, say, 1000 digits. The hardest part is to wirte the +, -, *, / operations.

If what you want is just to experiment with the math formula, you can choose another language, such as **Python**. It has data types like `Decimal, Fraction` that can do more precise calculating.

I love math so I do write a python script to test the formula:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
prec = 100
getcontext().prec = prec

fac = Decimal(1)/2
sum = Decimal(0)
eps = Decimal(0.1)
eps = eps**prec

realE = '2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995'

i = 3
while 1:
    ds = fac - fac/i
    sum += ds
    if ds < eps: break
    fac /= i * (i+1)
    i += 2

print 'After %d iteration:' % i
print realE
print str(1/sum)
```

Here's the result:

```
After 71 iteration:
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525166429
```

Comment: Your answer would be awesome if all I wanted was the result (i.e: the approximation of e with as many digits as possible). But I also need accurate time measurements of the process, and the number of bytes required to store the result, which is why I wrote in C++. I figured C++ would be better at handling low level stuffs like that. Also, it's an assignment for a Computer Organization class, and our professor isn't very fond of Python, because it's too high level.

Comment: So it's a homework. Then I think using a C++ library is also not accepted? You may implement the Python's Decimal class in C++ then you can use it to port the above code to C++.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the limit where the number added is much smaller than the sum, and because floats are basically rational numbers, this is cut off. Here is a good read about [the subtleties of floating point numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Example:

```
 12345.123
+    0.0001
------------
 12345.123
```

if only the first 8 digits are saved in a number.

A easy fix would be to iterate from range to 0, so that you start your sum with the small numbers, and to keep track of the lost digits. As an example:

```
sum0 = 12345.123
b0   =     0.0001
sum1 = sum0 + b0 # 12345.123
diff1 = (sum1 - sum0) - b0 # 0.0001
# the result you want is sum1 + diff1

# keep on iterating and summing
```

Comment: This is not a fix for  the limits of FP precision -- regardless of the method of summation, the final result can have only so many digits.

Comment: @quant_dev you can, if you keep track of the remainder (diff1). This is how sliding mean calculations work.

Comment: True, but you'll never express it as a single floating point number, which the OP was trying to do.